# SCNPlane's height not animating

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit

I'm animating a plane's height using this code.

```
func animPlane2(){
            let animSize = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "height")
            animSize.duration = 1.5
            animSize.byValue = 40
            animSize.repeatCount = Float.infinity
            animSize.autoreverses = true
            planeNode.addAnimation(animSize, forKey: nil)
        }
```

Debugger throws: 
[SCNKit ERROR] height is not an animatable path (from  | no child>)

The documentation on plane's height states:

> The extent of the plane along its vertical axis. Animatable.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SCNNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNNode) does not have a property named `height`. That's a property of the `SCNPlane` you have assigned as the node's geometry, so that's the part you need to add an animation to:

```
planeNode.geometry?.addAnimation(animSize, forKey: nil)
```

Alternately, you can add the animation to the node, but set its keyPath to affect the height of the geometry:

```
let animSize = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "geometry.height")
// ...
planeNode.addAnimation(animSize, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like your are trying to add the animation on the node instead of the geometry.